# Does a java switch case statement execute multiple cases for negative int values?

Tags: java, int, switch-statement

I just run over something strange in my java code:

```
switch (result) {
            case 0:
                result_amount = 500;
            case 1:
                result_amount = 600;
            case -1:
                result_amount = 700;
    }
```

`result` is from primitive type int.
For value `1` `case 1` and `case -1` are executed.

Is this a normal switch case behaviour? If yes: why?

Comment: from my point of view you should also always declare default at the end of the switch case.

Comment: but why does it go into the case for '-1'. Is '1' the same like '-1' for switch-case?

Comment: Because you haven't included a `break;` statement at the end of each case.

Comment: @MartinMiller because execution flow falls through `case 1` and `case -1`, as there is no `break` between them.

Answer (score 11):

You need to use the `break` keyword after a `case` block:

```
switch (result) {
        case 0:
            result_amount = all_amounts[i];
        break;
        case 1:
            result_amount = all_amounts[i];
        break;
        case -1:
            result_amount = all_amounts[i+1];
}
```

The `switch` statement will make a jump to the correct `case` tag, then execute all the code that follow, ignoring potential other `case` tags. You can consider the `switch` statement just like a `goto` one.

Answer (score 3):

**Fall Through.**

[quoting from docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

> The break statements are necessary because without them, statements in switch blocks fall through: All statements after the matching case label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of subsequent case labels, until a break statement is encountered.

You have to add the `break` after each case.

```
          case 1:
          result_amount = 600;
          break;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Remember**:

This is a mistake that almost every beginner will make. That's why I like C# more. It doesn't allow "fall-through".

What you did wrong is you fell-through the switch statement. Try using 0 as the value of `result`. It will go through all the cases. When a switch case finishes execution, the next case gets executed. That's why we need to add a `break;` statement for each case of the switch statement.

```
switch (result) {
            case 0:
                result_amount = 500;
                break;
            case 1:
                result_amount = 600;
                break;
            case -1:
                result_amount = 700;
                break;
}
```

But sometimes we want fall-through. For example when we want to calculate number of days in a month:

```
switch (month) {
    case 1:
    case 3:
    case 5:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 10:
    case 12:
        days = 31;
        break;
    case 2:
        days = 28;
    case 4:
    case 6:
    //Lots of code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without `break` statement next cases will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Generally Case Label Should be Integer / Constant
2. Negative numbers having no decimal point are also considered as Integer
3. Thus it is not necessary to have Case Labels greater than Zero

This is `fall through` condition.

```
        switch (result) {
                case 0:
                    result_amount = all_amounts[i];
                case 1:
                    result_amount = all_amounts[i];
                case -1:
                    result_amount = all_amounts[i+1];
        }
```

To avoid it you must put `break` statement

```
       switch (result) {
                case 0:
                    result_amount = all_amounts[i];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    result_amount = all_amounts[i];
                    break;
                case -1:
                    result_amount = all_amounts[i+1];
                    break;
        }
```

Now only matching case will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You should include break and default to run program in a proper way. Let me give you a example of it.

```
switch (result) {
            case 0:
                result_amount = 500;
             break;

            case 1:
                result_amount = 600;
            break;
            case -1:
                result_amount = 700;
            break;

    }
```